# Create a compatibility matrix

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I've got data as follows:

```
[attribute] [value]
foo yellow
foo green
foo red
foo blue
foo orange
foo cyan
foo magenta
foo white
foo brown
foo purple
```

[provided in this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/12764/0)

I'd like to transform data to a kind of frame for a compatibility matrix, which should look like ( cols and rows are based on attribute-values ):

```
        yellow green red blue orange cyan magenta white brown purple
yellow    x
green            x
red                   x
blue                      x
orange                          x
cyan                                  x
magenta                                      x
white                                               x
brown                                                     x
purple                                                          x
```

Same kinds of attributes should automatically be filled with `x`, all other combinations are set by the user later on. Since number of `values` per `attribute` may differ it would be nice if the transformation is done dynamically.

I made some shots using pivot / unpivot but only got cols ans rows changed - so only went half ( or quarter ;) ) the way.

Any help or tips are appreciated!

**Edit**: I've changed attribute-values of demo-data for better understanding. colors-values have been numbers before.

**Edit2**: According to and resulting of the updated answer of Stephan and the mentioned aim to get results dynamically, I added the following example-query. Perhaps someone can use it, having the same need. #data is a temp table providing the base data.

```
DECLARE     @SQL VARCHAR(MAX);
SET         @SQL = 'SELECT ' + '?placeholder?' + ' as name, '
SELECT @SQL = @SQL + case when row_number() over ( order by rand() ) > 1 then ',' else '' end +  'case value when ''' + cast( d.value as nvarchar ) + ''' then 1 else 0 end as "' +  cast( d.value as nvarchar ) + '"' from #data as d;
select @sql = @sql + ' from #data;'
set @SQL = replace( @sql, '?placeholder?', 'value' );
--select @SQL;
exec ( @sql )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly you can try this:

**EDIT** update to new requirements

```
CREATE TABLE `test_matrix_colors` (
  `color` varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO `test_matrix_colors` (`color`) VALUES
('yellow'),
('green'),
('red'),
('blue'),
('orange'),
('cyan'),
('magenta'),
('white'),
('brown'),
('purple');


SELECT 
    color,
    IF(color='yellow',1,0) as yellow,
    IF(color='green',1,0) as green,
    IF(color='red',1,0) as red,
    IF(color='blue',1,0) as blue,
    IF(color='orange',1,0) as orange,
    IF(color='cyan',1,0) as cyan,
    IF(color='magenta',1,0) as magenta,
    IF(color='white',1,0) as white,
    IF(color='brown',1,0) as brown,
    IF(color='purple',1,0) as purple
FROM 
    test_matrix_colors
WHERE 1
```

The results i obtained on local:

[image]

After that you can obtain any combination you need ... example blue-orange:

```
SELECT
    orange as blue_orange
FROM (
    SELECT 
        color,
        IF(color='yellow',1,0) as yellow,
        IF(color='green',1,0) as green,
        IF(color='red',1,0) as red,
        IF(color='blue',1,0) as blue,
        IF(color='orange',1,0) as orange,
        IF(color='cyan',1,0) as cyan,
        IF(color='magenta',1,0) as magenta,
        IF(color='white',1,0) as white,
        IF(color='brown',1,0) as brown,
        IF(color='purple',1,0) as purple
    FROM 
        test_matrix_colors
    WHERE 1
) as tmp
WHERE
    color = 'blue'
```

Comment: Nice idea, but: `IF(,,)` does not work on sql 2008. I changed this to `case .. when`. Furthermore, `value` is not included as first column as shown in estimated data - perhaps it was misunderstanding since 'value' in demo-data was set to 1 to 10 which also could be rownumber ;)

Comment: Sorry about the `IF` statement i wrote the query in mysql since this is what i have installed , can you some me exactly what data do you have or at least something close to it ?

Comment: I don't exactly understand your question! "demo data" is provided in the linked SQL fiddle. The estimated results are shown in the original post..!

Comment: ok i understand now so why can't you use the query provided by me ? si you have a lot of data and the value field is not consecutive it will still work you just need a script that will construct the query automatically

Comment: As already mentioned: I need a first column containing the "value" data!

Comment: maybe i was misleading you but in my answer `id` column represents the `value` column from your data

Comment: I know that. But ( example: ) How would you select the combination-result of pair za4, za5 from your example? I'd like sth like: `select za5 from table where type1 = za4`...

Comment: I've edited OP and changed attribute values from {1...10} to {yellow...purple}. Perhaps it's easier to understand for you now. The preceding question of mine in edited form would be: How would you select the value set for the combination of blue and/to orange? Don't misunderstand me. Your shot aims in the right direction, but I don't see how I could select a certain value in your result matrix by providing color(X) and color(Y)...

Comment: I've update the answer , pls let me know if its what you need

Comment: np, I'm glad that we finally reached a solution :D